Inverter/generator produces 120 VAC, I need 240 VAC with center tap (neutral)
My generator produces 31 amps at 120 VAC so I have been looking at 3/5 kVA step up transformers with 120X240 primary windings and 120/240 secondary windings. Problem is I am cheap and these things are expensive and even more expensive to ship.
Here is my question: Can I use a 5 kVA transformer that has a center-tapped 240 primary, or 2 × 120 volt primary windings, Ignore all the secondary windings, and connect my generator to one 120 volt winding (with both of them connected in series) and end up with an autotransformer that produces 110 on the unconnected winding, the neutral being the connection between the two and the gen connection being the other leg? I realize I could be dumping 3800 watts into one winding, but my intent is to end up with a L1 and a L2 that can produce 240 across them and 120 to neutral. Total load will average 1200 watts with a possible larger inrush when starting a pair of capacitor start split phase motors that operate on 220 and draw 4 amps each. This "system"  is for backup when power is out basically run a couple computers, few lights, refrigerator, and gate opener.

Yes, you can use a regular transformer as an autotransformer, if you stay within the core limits and the copper winding limits.
If you have a 5 kVA transformer with two 120 VAC windings in series, then the transformer windings should have been designed for 5000VA/240V = 20.8 A.
If you use a center-tap transformer, then the center-tap wire will have 2 x 20.8 A or 41.6 A, possibly creating an issue. Therefore, a transformer with 2 primary windings is preferred.
As for safety and code compliance, I am less certain. Fuse? Metal box?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Since this will actually power a building the center tap (neutral) connection current should never exceed half of transformer output as it will only carry unbalanced loads same as a house. Of course grounded metal box to protect and contain.

In theory, yes, in practice, not a great idea.  The transformer you use will be optimized for its designed use-case. You'll have to figure out the polarity of the windings, and at this power level, a mistake probably means burnt insulation and/or toxic fireball.  At power levels which easily kill animals, including your self.  Assuming you get things wired right without killing anything, you'll likely find lower efficiency, softer voltage regulation, and perhaps some distortion on the output.  We can't know if your loads will have issue with this.

Polarity is not an issue as long as I confirm connections with a low voltage AC source. I'm sure testing with a 5 amp fuse will prevent a "toxic fireball" If the primary is wound to carry 5KVA at 120 VAC Why would the efficiency be lowered?

Think about all the "empty" space taken up by the now unused secondary windings.
